# IR2110 Simulation not working in LTSPICE

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to implement a half bridge topology as shown in the figure below:
[image]

I have replaced the IRF450 with [STGW40H60DLFB IGBT](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stgw40h60dlfb.pdf).

I have also replaced the 11DF4 with [UF4007](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88755/uf4001.pdf).

My LTSPICE schematic looks like:
[image]

My VDS and VGS in the high side and low side is:
[image]

When I run my LTSPICE simulation with a pulse with 100K frequency, I get:
[image]

I can't spot a error in my LTSPICE, please let me know if you have any idea what it might be.

MODEL Used for UF4007:

```
.MODEL UF4007 D N=3.97671 IS=3.28772u RS=0.149734 EG=1.11 XTI=3 CJO=2.92655E-011 VJ=0.851862 M=0.334552 FC=0.5 TT=1.84973E-007 BV=1000 IBV=0.2 Iave=1 Vpk=1000 type=silicon
```

Spice Model for IR2100 was downloaded from:
https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/ir2110/

Spice Model for STGW40H60DLFB  was downloaded from:
https://www.digikey.be/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STGW40H60DLFB/497-14364-ND/4696260

Comment: Can you post the contents of the IR2110 subcircuit? It requires registration. You could to also post the contents of the `.asc` file, it would help. Use ``` as delimiters for the block of text.

Comment: No need for that, anymore. The problem is with your IGBT symbols, see the answer. It's safe to delete your comments.

Comment: I built the circuit using a FET and got the desired results, I will do further research on the circuit using the STGW40H60DLFB and mark your answer as correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you used an autogenerated symbol for your IGBT, but you connected it wrong, because the order of the pins is D-G-S. But, instead of using an autogenerated symbol you can make things easier for you if you choose the `[Misc]/nigbt` symbol, which you can use directly as an IGBT. All you have to do is rename `NIGBT` with `STGW40H60DLFB-V2`, and you're done.

---

You still have to add the correct prefix (right-click on the symbol, change `Z` to `X`), I thought that would be implied.

Anyway, the IGBT subcircuit is full of behavioural expressions and it's not very convergence-friendly. I don't know if it will help with your particular schematic, but I poked around and managed to get it working in a simple test by making these changes inside the `STGW40H60DLFB-V2.lib` file:

- on line `70` change `r_escusione 1z a1 500` to `c_escusione 1z a1 10p Rpar=500`
- on line `73` change `r_conv1 1y a1 10` to `c_conv1 1y a1 10p Rpar=10`
- on line `114` there's a `Grg1 ...`; add this line, `crg1 g2 g 10p rpar=1g` right below it
- on line `168` add a `;` at the beginning of the line, in front of `E2 ...`, then add these two lines below:

```
g2 50 40 g d1k 1k
r2 50 40 1m
```

- on line `204` add a `;` at the beginning of the line, in front of `E22 ...`, and add these two lines below:

```
G22 502 402 ss d1k 1k
r22 502 402 1m
```

You can help in your schematic by setting `Rser=10...100m` for the voltage sources (`V3`, `V4`, and `V1`; `V2` can be ignored), adding `Rser=1...10m` to capacitors (all four), and adding `Rpar=10...100k` to the inductor. Also try changing `V2`, `A1` and their connections like this:

- delete `A1` and all the connections to the input pins `HIN` and `LIN`. `V2` should be just sitting there in the schematic with no connections.
- add `[Digital]/buf` (**not** `buf1`) and connect its input to `V2` and its outputs to `HIN` and `LIN` pins. There should be a new `A1` in the schematic.
- add `vhigh=6 tau=10n tripdt=30n` to the new `A1`.

These changes could help, too:

- add `Vp=0.3` to the `.model UF4007` card
- add this model for the `1N4148`:

```
.model 1N4148 D(Is=2.52n Rs=.568 N=1.752 Cjo=4p M=.4 tt=20n Iave=200m Vpk=75 Vp=0.3 mfg=OnSemi type=silicon)
```

Try running your schematic with these changes. If you're religious, praying might help.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion above was correct. The problem was with my IGBTs. I tried to use the
**STGW40H60DLFB-V2** by choosing the **[Misc]/nigbt** symbol as suggested above but I couldn't get it to work. So, I used a FET model which can withstand high voltage and the circuit worked. The simulation served its purpose. The correct simulation looks like:
[image]

The results from the simulation looks like:
[image]

**V(n008)** is the input PWN signal to HIN pin.
**V(n0011)** is the inverted input PWN signal to LOW pin.
**V(n003)** is the Drain-Source Voltage of the HIGH side.
**V(n003,n004)** is the Gate-Source Voltage of the HIGH side.
**V(n004)** is the Drain-Source Voltage of the LOW side.
**V(n0010)** is the Gate-Source Voltage of the HIGH side.

In order to simulate this circuit properly without getting errors, the settings in the **Tools\ControlPanel\SPICE** has to be changed as:
[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if it helps.